# bs4 row.find routine adds \n to the end of the string variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, append

I have a list of strings in python LIST say tickers[]. When I am trying to add another string member (say ticker which is a string variable) to the end of the list using tickers.append(ticker), the append adds \n to the list! Any idea about what is the problem?

ticker variable comes from the following code:

```
resp=requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'lxml')
table=soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
tickers=[]
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    ticker=row.findAll('td')[0].text
    tickers.append(ticker)
```

Actually I am trying to reach the list of tickers from wikipedia with the following function and the \n creates problem when I am trying to use the tickers list members for further process:

```
def save_sp500_tickers():
resp=requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'lxml')
table=soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
tickers=[]
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    ticker=row.findAll('td')[0].text
    tickers.append(ticker)
with open("sp500tickers.pickle","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(tickers,f)
return tickers
```

Comment: Try to append ticker.strip("\n")

Comment: then append doesnt add the "\n" its already there in ticket. you can see this by printing between the row.findall and the append `print(bytes(ticker.encode('utf-8')))` as @ThunderHorn said, you can just strip the new line from ticker

Comment: When I print the tickers list it look as this:
    print(tickers)
['MMM\n', 'ABT\n', 'ZION\n', 'ZTS\n']

\n comes from nowhere?

Comment: yeah because the variable ticker on each loop has a new line in it. its nothing to to do with the append. when you print the byte value of ticker before the append it shows `b'MMM\n'`. So the issue isnt with the append at all, the text has a new line char in it so if you want to remove it then do what thunderhorn says

Comment: Fine, you are right I tried ticker.strip("\n") and now it is ok. Thank you for your comments.